# Azure DevOPS: Redeploying an older release (one stage only) did not deploy the older changes

Tags: azure-devops

Our team had to test something in an older release. I went to the Release that was needed to be redeployed. We only needed one App to be redeployed, so I went inside the older release from the list and clicked "Redeploy" to that one particular stage.

When the deployment were done, I found that it actually deployed the latest changes. Am I using an incorrect method to redeploy an older release to only one stage? Should I create a brand new release pointing to older artifacts instead?

Answer (score 1):

This is just opinion, but I think that better apporach is to create a new release pointing to older artfact. Why? Because you have clear perspective what was deplyed and what is currently available. Otherwise, you may get false perspective.